# Using jQuery with Angular2 inside *ngif is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have Countdown jQuery function inside my Angular2 *ngIf and it is not working. I don't have any error in my console.log, but the div is empty. It's just showing the title (h1).
Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="isDataAvailable"><h1>Dashboard</h1><div id="kodeCountdown"></div></div>
```

Angular2 TypeScript Component

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.getData().then(() => this.isDataAvailable = true); 
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
        if ($('#kodeCountdown').length) {
            var austDay = new Date();
            austDay = new Date(2017, 3, 2, 12, 10);
            jQuery('#kodeCountdown').countdown({ until: austDay });
            jQuery('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        }
    }
```

Result:
**Dashboard**

Comment: not very familiar with A2 - but don't you need to reference the controller in the ngIf? eg - ngIf="sampleController.isDataAvailable"....

Comment: Actually I have a title inside this tag as well and It's just showing the Title (h1) and not the countdown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the [`ngAfterViewInit` method](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html) is only called once after the component's view has been initialized. Since the `*ngIf` condition hasn't been evaluated to `true` when `ngAfterViewInit` is called, your `#kodeCountdown` element isn't visible which means that your countdown function isn't initialized.

One way to resolve this would be to execute that logic inside of the [`ngAfterViewChecked` method](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewChecked-class.html) (instead of the [`ngAfterViewInit` method](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html) ), because then your code will be executed *after* `*ngIf` has been evaluated:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getData().then(() => this.isDataAvailable = true);
}
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if ($('#kodeCountdown').length) {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(2017, 3, 2, 12, 10);
    jQuery('#kodeCountdown').countdown({
      until: austDay
    });
    jQuery('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
  }
}
```

However, since the `ngAfterViewChecked` method is called after every check of the component's view, you will need to add additional logic to ensure that your countdown logic is only implemented once. You could simply set a flag to handle that:

```
private isCountdownInitialized: boolean;

// ...

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (!this.isCountdownInitialized && $('#kodeCountdown').length) {
    this.isCountdownInitialized = true;

    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A way around this is to set up jQuery code in a child component to free it of the parent's use of of ngIf restriction.

Comment: how do you do that?